# Getting error when Integrating LDAP with Wordpress

Tags: ldap, wordpress, openldap, pam-ldap, mod-auth-ldap

I have installed Ldap on Ubuntu 14.04 and wordpress on amazon linux ami.
I'm able to login in ldap console. I have created a user in it.
On wordpress i have installed simpleLDAP plugin.
I don't know where i'm going wrong on the configuration part.
The error that i get when i login into Wordpress admin panel is :

> Simple LDAP Login: Simple LDAP Login could not authenticate your
>   credentials. The security settings do not permit trying the WordPress
>   user database as a fallback.

I'm attaching the snapshot of simple LDAP plugin settings that i configured on wordpress.
Please help me solve this error.

[Simple LDAP plugin settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WOpU.png)

Comment: check if SElinux is causing issues, try disabling it or change the value of boolean like this: setsebool -P httpd_can_connect_ldap 1 or check if LDAP default port  is open in Firewall and AWS security console

Comment: i haven't verified it but also check https://wordpress.org/support/topic/configuration-notes-errors-should-be-fixed?replies=2

Comment: ok..check firewall and AWS security policy of server if LDAP is hosted on AWS

Comment: Firewall allows all traffic and SElinux is disabled.

Comment: error clearly says can't contact LDAP server..see if your LDAP server is reachable from your wordpress installation..did you try desabling SELINUX or change the sebool values

Comment: I think i have not configured the plugin right. I have attached a link in my question please have a look.

Comment: did you anonymize the plugin setting? If not the domain controller entry is very likely wrong. Please fix it with the real ldap server address or localhost if ldap server is the same box.

Comment: My Ldap server ip is 52.xx.xx.xx, so should i use https://52.xx.xx.xx or ldap://52.xx.xx.xx?

Answer (score 1):

in the screenshot you post the domain controller is 'ldap://dc1.test.com'.

In the plugin (very scarce) documentation, you clearly see that there is no 'ldap', so just plain 'dc1.test.com': [screenshot ldap plugin wordpress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-ldap-login/screenshots/)

So that would explain the 'can't contact ldap server' syslog errors.

Comment: If i will mention dc1.test.com in the domain controller, then how will it contact my Ldap server. My Ldap server has Public Ip. So, I think i should use the public ip for that. Example: Ldap is installed on 52.xx.xx.xx/ldap so, should i use this url or only ip?

Comment: you should use the dns name or ip address needed to reach your ldap server. What I meant is that you do not need to use the uri part (the ldap:// before the host name)

Comment: Tried using ip only it doesn't work.

Comment: then you will need to verify you can contact the ldap host from your wordpress host using ldap tools. Until then, 'it doesn't work' is, I guess, all you will get from here.